# SQL server pivot + sum + group by

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum, pivot, aggregate-functions

I have data as following and i need to group sum pivot

| AA | BB | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | 01/01/2020 |
| a | 2 | 01/01/2020 |
| b | 5 | 01/01/2020 |
| b | 1 | 01/01/2020 |
| c | 5 | 01/01/2020 |
| d | 1 | 01/01/2020 |
| d | 8 | 02/01/2020 |
| e | 1 | 01/01/2020 |

what I obtain with my sql code

|  | a | b | c | d | e |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2020 | 3 | 6 | 5 | 1 | 1 |
| 02/01/2020 | / | / | / | 8 | / |

what I need to obtain: a and d grouped as f and c and e grouped as g and b separate

|  | b | f | g |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2020 | 6 | 4 | 6 |
| 02/01/2020 | / | 8 | / |

I have got the following sql but I cant seem to do the group summing. Do you do it before pivoting or after?

```
SELECT * FROM(
SELECT AA,Date
FROM [dbo].[Data] )
AS SourceTable 
PIVOT(SUM([BB]) 
FOR [AA] IN([a],[b],[c],[d],[e])) 
AS PivotTable
```

IF I try this it doesnt work

```
SELECT * FROM(
SELECT AA,Date
FROM [dbo].[Data] )
AS SourceTable 
PIVOT(SUM([BB]) 
FOR [AA] IN([a]+[d],[b],[c]+[e])) 
AS PivotTable
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation as follows:

```
select sum(case when aa in ('a','d') then BB  end) as f,
       sum(case when aa in ('c','e') then BB  end) as g,
       sum(case when aa = 'b' then BB  end) as b
  from table_name
group by date
```

Answer (score 2):

I find that this is simpler done with conditional aggregation:

```
select 
    date,
    sum(case when d.aa = 'b'         then bb else 0 end) as b,
    sum(case when d.aa in ('a', 'd') then bb else 0 end) as f,
    sum(case when d.aa in ('c', 'e') then bb else 0 end) as g
from data d
group by date
```